# Inquiry regarding Security considerations for Nginx Docker image

Tags: nginx, security, docker, port, user-accounts

I am currently exploring the usage of an Nginx Docker image within our project. I am seeking more information about the security considerations and best practices associated with using your Docker image.

As my aim is to run nginx listening on port 443 in secure way.

Here are a few specific questions I have:

1. Are there recommended approaches or best practices for enabling the container to listen to port 443?
2. How to run official containers that are using root internally in a secure way?
3. Security of Docker with Root Privileges: with reference to the attached link https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/4bf0763f4977fff7e9648add59e0540088f3ca9f/mainline/debian/Dockerfile, which indicates that Docker operates with root-level privileges, could you elaborate on the security measures in place to mitigate potential risks associated with running Docker as a root user?
4. Non-Root Operation: I am interested in understanding how nginx operates as a non-root user and listen to port 443 within a Docker container.

Any information or guidance you can provide would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Security best practices always begin with requirements of the organization. A bank for example wants an nginx docker container to be secured in a very different way than for example a small business.

Comment: Please could you list the resources you have already consulted?

Comment: You don't seem to understand security principles nor docker, nor containers. Even if you asked properly how would you assess any answers?